# What is the purpose of using only the coil of a relay?

Tags: relay

In these two examples:
http://www.electronicecircuits.com/electronic-circuits/cd4060-timer-circuit-1-minute-to-2-hours/comment-page-4#comment-48679
http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/ronj/24hs.html
A relay is used to, well ...
...Why are they used?
Exluding the relay doesn't seem to change anything but the nice click sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relays are shown unconnected because it's up to the user as to how he/she wants to use them.  The schematics shown are timer circuits, so commonly you might hook the relay contacts to a light or to turn something off after a preset time (coffee maker?).  It's not shown since the circuit is meant for general purpose applications.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you connect the unit to be controlled to the relay's switch contacts. For a reactive load (like an electric motor), some protection of the relay contacts should be used, e.g. a flyback diode for DC, otherwise arcing will reduce their lifespan and possibly make them stick together.